# Merge tuples and numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, tuples, fusion, or-operator

I would like to know how to turn some tuples with numpy arrays containing different numbers, into a unique tuple, with just an array, containing all the numbers. For example:

```
a=(array([0,11]),) 
b=(array([12]),) 
c=merge(a,b)=(array([0,11,12]),)
```

---

Could someone help me? I am still not used to numpy...
a and b were found using numpy.where() and display exactly as written up there. I tried this, but did not work:

```
c=a or b
```

---

Thanks a lot for helping me ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def merg():
    a=(np.array([0,11]),) 
    b=(np.array([12]),)
    return tuple(np.hstack([a,b]))
```

Results:

```
>>> merg()
(array([ 0, 11, 12]),)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me for sure  ! :)